# Problemas con select dinamico - dependiente ajax, mysql y php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Trato de crear un select dinamico/dependiente con ajaxx y este a pesar de que genera resultados de regreso, no puedo darle valor al elemento html. 
Acá el codigo:

```
 <script>
      // Agarra el ajaxx de país.
    $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#paisselect').on('change',function(){ 
              var pais=$('select#paisselect').find(":selected").val();
               if(pais){
                console.log(pais);
                    $.ajax({
                        data:{pais:pais},
                        type:'POST', //mandar variables como post o get
                        url:'config/database.php', //url que recibe las variables
                        dataType :'html',
                        success:function(html){
                          $("#region").html(html);
                        }
                   });
               }            
  });     
});     
  </script>
```

html:

```
<label for="region"> Estado/Region: </label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" value="">
```

PHP consulta de datos:

```
 if(!empty($pais) && !empty($pais)){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM regiones where id_pais='.$pais.'";
        $resultado_regiones = $conn->query($sql);
        if($resultado_regiones->num_rows > 0) 
        {
        while($rowsregiones = $resultado_regiones->fetch_object())
        {       
           echo '<option>'.$rowsregiones->nombre.' </option';
        }
        }


    }
```

Agradecido estaria con la ayuda.

Comment: Estás asignando el resultado a un elemento cuyo id es `region`, aquí: `$("#region").html(html);`  pero el select tiene la id `exampleFormControlSelect2` debes igualarlo a uno u otro... Por ejemplo, cambia el `id` del `select` así: `<select class="form-control" id="region" value="">`  .... Y, supongo que hay más para abajo una etiqueta de cierre: `</select>`

Answer (score 1):

En el success de la llamada ajax quieres insertar los resultados en el elemento con id "region" pero el select no tiene el atributo id adecuado. Debes ponerle el atributo id="region"

```
<select class="form-control" id="region" value="">
```

Aunque esto no creo que te vaya a interferir, te has olvidado del simbolo ">" en tu etiqueta de cierre de los options:

```
echo '<option>'.$rowsregiones->nombre.' </option';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos errores:

- En el `success` asignas los resultados a un elemento cuyo id sería `region`, pero el select que muestras tiene otro id.
- En el PHP tus `option` no se crean con el formato adecuado que sería: `<option value="value1">Value 1</option>` y hay errores de sintaxis. Además haces dos evaluaciones idénticas en el `if`

Pasamos a corregir:

#### HTML

```
<label for="region"> Estado/Region: </label>
<select class="form-control" id="region">
</select>
```

Asegúrate que ningún otro elemento tenga el id `region`.

#### PHP

```
if( !empty($pais) )
{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM regiones where id_pais='.$pais.'";
    $resultado_regiones = $conn->query($sql);
    if($resultado_regiones->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($rowsregiones = $resultado_regiones->fetch_object())
        {       
            $region=$rowsregiones->nombre; 
            echo "<option value=\"$region\">$region</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

En `value`, si quieres, puedes poner otro dato, como el `id` de la región si existiera.

Comment: Valiosa respuesta, me ayudo! Gracias.